# Logic: In_example_2

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

Here is the code from the book:

```
Example In_example_2 :
  forall n, In n [2; 4] ->
  exists n', n = 2 * n'.
Proof.
  (* WORKED IN CLASS *)
  simpl.
  intros n [H | [H | []]].
  - exists 1. rewrite <- H. reflexivity.
  - exists 2. rewrite <- H. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

After `simpl.` `In` is transformed into a disjunction of 3 elements:

```
============================
forall n : nat, 2 = n \/ 4 = n \/ False -> exists n' : nat, n = n' + (n' + 0)
```

But I totally don't understand how to read this:

```
intros n [H | [H | []]].
```

It produced this:

```
n : nat
H : 2 = n
============================
exists n' : nat, n = n' + (n' + 0)

subgoal 2 (ID 229) is:
 exists n' : nat, n = n' + (n' + 0)
```

What I understood:

1. It put n from `forall` into the context.
2. It split disjunction of 3 elements into 2 subgoals, ignoring False:
3. Created 2 subgoals according to the number of splits.

There is also a notice at the bottom:

```
(** (Notice the use of the empty pattern to discharge the last case
    _en passant_.) *)
```

> En passant (French: [ɑ̃ paˈsɑ̃], lit. in passing) is a move in
>   chess. It is a special pawn capture that can only occur immediately
>   after a pawn makes a move of two squares from its starting square, and
>   when it could have been captured by an enemy pawn had it advanced only
>   one square.

Looking at this:

```
intros n [H | [H | []]].
```

Can somebody explain me:

1. Should command of this form be used for destructing forall? Is there something else for this task?
2. How to read this command in English?
3. Why `[H | []]` was put into another pair of brackets?
4. How `[]` told coq to ignore the False statement?
5. When this command should be used in general?

Comment: What do you mean by "foreach"?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim I meant forall. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `intros n [H | [H | []]]` form is a shorthand for

```
intros n H. destruct H as [H | [H | []]].
```

You can further rewrite the proof as

```
intros n H. destruct H as [H2 | H4F].
- (* H2 : 2 = n *)
  exists 1. rewrite <- H2. reflexivity.
- (* H4F : 4 = n \/ False *)
  destruct H4F as [H4 | HF].
  + (* H4 : 4 = n *)
    exists 2. rewrite <- H4. reflexivity.
  + (* HF : False *)
    destruct HF. (* No more subgoals here *)
```

The two proofs are logically equivalent, but the first one is shorter (and easier to read, once you get used to the syntax).

Generally speaking, the tactic `destruct x as [...]` takes the expression `x` and generates one subgoal for each constructor that could have been used to produce `x`.  The arguments to the constructors are named according to the pattern `[...]`, and the parts corresponding to the different constructors are separated by vertical bars.

A proposition of the form `A \/ B \/ C` should be read as `A \/ (B \/ C)`.  Thus, when you call `destruct` for the first time in the expanded form above, you get two cases: when for when `A` holds, the other one for when `B \/ C` holds.  You need to call `destruct` a second time to analyze the inner or, which is why you had nested brackets in the original expression.  As for the last branch, `False` is defined as a proposition with no constructors, so once you destruct a hypothesis `HF : False`, the proof is complete.

(Here, "*en passant*" [is equivalent to the English "in passing"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/en%20passant), roughly meaning "incidentally". It refers to the fact that we are discharging the last case as a by-product of doing a case analysis on the or hypothesis.)